# The convexity of a function $e^{x+y}$

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

The question is to text the function $$e^{x+y}$$ and determine if it's convex, concave or not.

As $(e^x)' = e^x$, all four second derivatives in a Hessian matrix will be the same:
$$H=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        e^{x+y} & e^{x+y} \\
        e^{x+y} & e^{x+y} \\
        \end{bmatrix}$$

And so the determinant will be naturally equal to zero.

Does it mean that the function is neither concave nor convex? Or it only means I should use another test to determine the convexity or concavity?

Thanks,
Paul

Comment: why not check from the definition? Given $(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2),t\in[0,1]$ then we have that $t(x_1,y_1)+(1-t)(x_2,y_2)=(tx_1+(1-t)x_2,ty_1+(1-t)y_2)$ whose sum of coordinates is $t(x_1+y_1)+(1-t)(x_2+y_2)$ which should lie between $(x_i+y_i), i=1,2$, ruling out both convexity and concavity.

Answer (score 2):

Apply a change of coordinates in the following way:

$$X=x+y \quad Y=x-y.$$

So your function become $e^X$, which is constant along straight lines parallel to $X-$axis.

Now the Hessian matrix is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
e^X & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},
$$

which is diagonal and its eigenvalues are $0$ and $e^X$ which are non negative for every point $(X_0,Y_0)$, so the matrix is positive semidefinite, thus the function in convex.

Answer (score 0):

$f: z \mapsto e^z$ is a convex function on $\mathbb R$ and $g: (x, y) \mapsto x + y$ is a linear mapping from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$. What can you say about the composition $f \circ g$ ?